# Not able to create S3 bucket in specific region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a bucket using AWS Java API but not able to create in any region except US_WEST_1.

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetBucketLocationRequest;

public class CreateBucket {
    private static String bucketName     = "hellobucket6434";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));


            if(!(s3client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)))
            {
                // Note that CreateBucketRequest does not specify region. So bucket is 
                // created in the region specified in the client.
                s3client.createBucket(new CreateBucketRequest(
                        bucketName));
            }
            // Get location.
            String bucketLocation = s3client.getBucketLocation(new GetBucketLocationRequest(bucketName));
            System.out.println("bucket location = " + bucketLocation);

         }
```

Below is the error thrown when tried to execute:

```
[ERROR] /C:/Users/surya/Desktop/aws-java-sample/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/samp
les/CreateBucket.java:[20,52] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable AP_SOUTH_1
[ERROR]   location: class com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/Regions.html), AP_SOUTH_1 is a valid enum constant. Can some please let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Which version of the SDK you are using? It seems you are using some old version.

Comment: Most likely a version issue. Can also try cleaning your project with your IDE.

Comment: Version 1.9.6 ...

Comment: That's prehistoric.  Upgrade your SDK.  Mumbai was introduced in June of 2016.  Your SDK is from November of 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regions is introduced in [AWS SDK for Java 1.11.11](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/51428ab65a35a309c7853e91401f40f456d5b159/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/regions/Regions.java). Upgrade to at least this version to use the region. NOTE: It is better to use latest version always.